# Scan all files in a directory and return counts by file type

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I have just joined an IT company & started working with ColdFusion. My Manager wants me to write code in ColdFusion which:

1. Will scan any directory (say `c:\cf\`) which contains hundreds of files including jQuery files, cfm files etc. and give the counts of such files (we can manually select which file type to show).

I wrote this code:

```
    <cfdirectory
        action="list"
        directory="direcoty path" 
        name="Files"
        recurse = "yes"
        filter="*.*" />         
    <cfoutput>No of Java Script: #files.recordCount#</cfoutput>
```

but it shows one file type at a time. How can I check multiple file types at the same time?

Comment: Are you *really* after an answer that works on all version of ColdFusion 7->10 (as per how you've tagged the question)?

Comment: Your first example I assume you are really specifying `filter="*.js"` for just the JS files, right?

Comment: Also you're really asking 2 different questions here - how to count multiple filetypes in a directory, and how to search multiple files for some string.   You should post the 2nd part of this question as a new question I think

Comment: @Adam my manager told me just get me the code for any later version of coldfusion. I enquired the IT about the version we are using on the development server. they replied its 7 and there is no plan to migrate to later version. so I guess i want it to run on CF 7 only as of now.

Comment: @duncan Ya i figured it out that it need to be done seperatly. But my manager is not from IT background He just tell me to do things which he dont know are possible or not!
Anyway i am posting second part as a new question now

Comment: _"its 7 and there is no plan to migrate"_ - that's a [very old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion#Release_history) version to be writing new code for. :/ Have they given any reason why they are sticking to old and unsupported software?

Comment: @Peter Yes our client are using the application for a long time and they dont want any changes to that. Its a very old project which is there with our company for around 13-14 years now and the applications are still more or less same as it was developed in the begining.

Comment: If they don't want any changes then why are you making changes?  More specifically, does "not wanting changes" mean they don't want the security flaws fixed - because there almost certainly _are_ security issues with CF7 - ones that were fixed in 8/9/10 but _not_ fixed for CF7 (because it has been unsupported for years).

Comment: Thanks SKChauhan. I was asking because the best approach would differ from version to version, so it's good to be precise with your tagging. BTW: I agree with @PeterBoughton that it is a risk to be running a CFMX7 server these days. Is it public-facing?

Comment: Not at all its for internal use of the client's company only

Comment: _( So was the recently taken Adobe source code. ;) )_

Comment: Since you are new to ColdFusion, let me introduce you to the cfdump tag, the programmer's best freind.  In this case <cfdump var="#Files#" will show you what you have to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, there's two approaches.  Either loop over each of the different file types you're interested in, doing a cfdirectory for each.

```
<cfset filetypes = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset arrayAppend(filetypes, "js")>
<cfset arrayAppend(filetypes, "cfm")>
<cfset arrayAppend(filetypes, "pdf")>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(filetypes)#">
    <cfdirectory
        action="list"
        directory="directory path" 
        name="Files"
        recurse = "yes"
        filter="*.#filetypes[i]#" />         
    <cfoutput>No of #filetypes[i]# files: #files.recordCount#<br></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Or you can do multiple file types in one CFDirectory, see http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1221-CFDirectory-Filtering-Uses-Pipe-Character-For-Multiple-Filters-Thanks-Steve-Withington-.htm

```
<cfdirectory
    action="list"
    directory="directory path" 
    name="Files"
    recurse = "yes"
    filter="*.js|*.cfm|*.pdf" />         
<cfoutput>No of JS/CFM/PDF files: #files.recordCount#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! the first approach is displaying the combined count of all the files instead of individual count. like:
No of js files: 282
No of txt files: 0
No of cfm files: 0

Comment: @SKChauhan curious, it works for me.  Or does this just mean that you only have .js files in your directory?

Comment: i had to write the code multiple time, changing the filter for txt, cfm files each time then it shows correct count.

Comment: Sorry, my original answer won't work as it is on CF 7, due to the way I'm looping over the array of filetypes.  I've rewritten it to work for you.

Comment: I worled it out. i am now repeating the above code for every file type in the code because
    <cfset filetypes = ["js", "cfm", "pdf"]>
doesnt work in the CF 7.

Comment: ah yes, that shorthand way of declaring an array wasn't added until CF 8.  I've updated my answer to still use an array, that will work with CF 7