# Get number of files in various subdirectories relative to the current page - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, directory, cfdirectory

I have some cf code which is almost working I think.

I have the following structure:

```
work
--still-life
--portraits
--personal
```

In each of these folders there is the same structure:

```
still-life
  --img-s
  --img-m
  --img-l
```

I want to know how many files are in the first directory `(img-s)` for each of the pages that I am on `/still-life/index.cfm` for example.

I have been trying to implement cfdirectory, but to no avail, then I found this code which is almost working:

```
<cfoutput>
directory="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetTemplatePath())#"
</cfoutput>

<cfdirectory 
  directory="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetTemplatePath())#" 
  name="myDirectory" 
  sort="name ASC, size DESC, datelastmodified">
<!---- Output the contents of the cfdirectory as a cftable -----> 
<cftable 
  query="myDirectory" 
  colSpacing = "10"
  htmltable 
  colheaders> 
  <cfcol 
    header="NAME:" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#Name#"> 
  <cfcol 
    header="SIZE:" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#Size#"> 
  <cfcol 
    header="date last modified:" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#datelastmodified#"> 
</cftable>
```

I am actually getting this in the output:

```
directory="{URL}\work\portraits\"
NAME:     SIZE: date last modified:
img-l     0     {ts '2015-06-08 11:56:35'}
img-m     0     {ts '2015-06-08 11:56:35'}
img-s     0     {ts '2015-06-08 11:56:36'}
index.cfm 134   {ts '2015-06-08 11:56:36'}
```

So I think it is pretty close. I am wondering if I need a loop to go through the subdirectories?

If it helps I only really care about img-s directory and the files should always be jpg's.

I did try and implement some of the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22857248/1238244) and [here](http://www.easycfm.com/forums/printthread.cfm?Forum=12&Topic=3348) as well as trying to implement ExpandPath function (but my CF experience is relatively limited).

**EDIT**

I've added this to the bottom of the cftable:

```
 <cfcol    
        header="Count"
        align="left"
        width="20"
        text="#recordCount#">
```

And now my output looks like this:

```
NAME:      SIZE:    date last modified:         Count
img-l      0        {ts '2015-06-08 11:56:34'}  4
img-m      0        {ts '2015-06-08 11:56:34'}  4
img-s      4096     {ts '2015-06-08 14:10:33'}  4
index.cfm  1276     {ts '2015-06-08 14:13:53'}  4
```

So at least it is now reading the filesize of the directory.

**EDIT 2**

Just for @ScottStroz here is the current code:

```
<cfset filters = "*.jpg">
<cfdirectory 
    directory="#ExpandPath('.')#/img-s" 
    name="getSubDir"
    recurse = "yes"
    filter = "#filters#">

    <cfset imgArray=arraynew(1)>
    <cfset i=1>
    <cfset imgDir="img-s/">
    <cfset imgDirM="img-m/">
    <cfloop query="getSubDir">
        <cfset imgArray[i]=getSubDir.name>
        <cfset i = i + 1>
    </cfloop>

    <ul class="workNav clearfix">
        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(imgArray)#" index="i">
            <cfoutput>
                <li><a href="#imgDirM##imgArray[i]#"><img src="#imgDir##imgArray[i]#"/></a></li>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfloop>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why, in the name of all that is holy, are you using `cftable`?

Comment: @ScottStroz it's true I discovered the code on the webulator. You are free to edit or add your own answer, if you seek to win my favour ;)
I prefer to output stuff inside a UL. To be fair it is displaying tabular data, but I only need this to prove the function is working, it will be used later to generate html output (so no cftable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work.

```
<cfoutput>
directory="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetTemplatePath())#"
</cfoutput>

<cfdirectory 
  directory="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetTemplatePath())#" 
  name="myDirectory" 
  sort="name ASC, size DESC, datelastmodified"
  recurse = "yes">
<!---- Output the contents of the cfdirectory as a cftable -----> 
<cftable 
  query="myDirectory" 
  colSpacing = "10"
  htmltable 
  colheaders> 
  <cfcol    
        header="Count"
        align="left"
        width="20"
        text="#recordCount#">
  <cfcol 
    header="NAME:" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#Name#"> 
  <cfcol 
    header="SIZE:" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#Size#"> 
  <cfcol 
    header="date last modified:" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#datelastmodified#"> 
    <cfcol 
    header="Directory" 
    align = "Left"
    width = 20
    text="#directory#"> 
</cftable>
```

Comment: I am tempted to vote this down because you left in the references to `cftable`. :D

Comment: @ScottStroz Well, you are free to do so. But, is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Yes...because using `cftable` is asinine.